# installing npm in Laravel in order to use Bootstrap in my project

Tags: laravel, npm, cmd

i'm new to laravel and it's been a while that i'm trying to install bootstrap files(css and js) .
i first did this in cmd :

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

which ended in

> Package manifest generated successfully.

then :

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

that showed me :

> Bootstrap scaffolding installed successfully.
>   Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.

but now when i execute `npm install` in cmd , it shows me an error :

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

what the hell is wrong with it ??

Comment: First run node -v and npm -v to make sure you have node installed on your machine. If not, go to    [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download)  to download and install node js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you either don't have npm installed on your device or you don't have your path mapped to where the command is held. How you solve that problem depends on what operating system you are on.

https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

If it's installed but not recognized as a command, then you need to add it to your path:

1. Open start in the taskbar and search "environment" and click `edit the system environment variables`.
2. Click the `environment variables` button. There should be a "Path" variable for either the user or system. If the user has one, click to edit it.
3. Click `new` and give it the path to the directory that contains the node command (e.g. `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`).
4. Press `OK` and then restart your terminal/powershell and try again.

Comment: First run node -v and npm -v to make sure you have node installed on your machine. If not, go to    [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download)  to download and install node js

Comment: i've installed **node js**.
what now??
i ran both `node -v` & `npm -v` , but it answered me :
_'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file_
@ClintWinter

Comment: If it's installed but not recognized as a command, then you need to add it to your path. 1) open start and search "environment" and click "edit the system environment variables". 2) Click "evironment variables" button. There should be a "Path" variable for either the user or system. If the user has one, click to edit it. 3) Click "new" and give it the path to the directory that contains the node command (e.g. "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"). 4) Press OK and then restart your terminal/powershell and try again.

Comment: i dont know how , (it's weird to me too) but my IDE (phpstorm) today showed a notification that i can install node js package and when i accepted , the in-software terminal showed up and and codes started running , after a couple of minutes it was done...
thanks for everyone